# Nil:List[Int] as parameter

Tags: scala, list

I have following trait definition:

```
sealed trait List[+A]

// `List` data type, parameterized on a type, `A`
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]

// A `List` data constructor representing the empty list
/* Another data constructor, representing nonempty lists. Note that `tail` is another `List[A]`,
which may be `Nil` or another `Cons`.
 */
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
```

and a function:

```
  def add1(l: List[Int]): List[Int] =
    foldRight(l, Nil:List[Int])((h,t) => Cons(h+1,t))
```

My question is, what does `Nil:List[Int]` mean? Does it mean, I pass a `Nil` list with type with `Int` notation?

Comment: Here it's same as `List.empty[Int]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `fold` (and it variants) is determining the type parameter based on the first parameter list, you cannot simply pass `Nil`, as the type would be derived as `List[Nothing]` (you would also see the second parameter list not matching). You can use type ascription to tell the `Nil` is of type `List[Int]`. You could also pass the `List[Int]` as the type parameter:

```
foldRight[List[Int]](l, Nil)((h,t) => Cons(h+1,t))
```

For the reference, `foldRight` signature is this:

```
def foldRight[B](z: B)(op: (A, B) => B): B
```